# Unable to return JSON Array from the @Controller class throwing No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject error

Tags: java, json, spring, elasticsearch, spring-restcontroller

Am fetching documents from Elasticsearch via ActiveMQ using `@Controller`. Am calling my client method with parameter and getting response from Elastic Search as JSONArray but while am returning JSONArray from my `@Controller` class am getting the below error

Please find my error below.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1191) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:312) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
```

Please find my `@Controller` class and my @ResponseBody method

```
@Controller
public class SearchProductWebService {
    private static final String DOCUMENTS = "/document/{name}";
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SearchProductWebService.class.getName());

    com.demo.earchengineclient.Client searchEngineClient = com.demo.searchengineclient.Client.getInstance();

    @RequestMapping(value = DOCUMENTS, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Object getDocumentByName(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, @PathVariable("name") String name) {
        System.out.println("Search Documents--->"+searchEngineClient.searchByDocuments("arthi"));
        return searchEngineClient.searchByDocuments(name);
    }

}
```

Please find my client code implementation :

```
public JSONArray searchByDocuments(String name) {
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    request.put("method", "search_by_documents");
    request.put("name", name);
    this.start();
    JSONObject response = producer.post(request, 60);
    this.stop();
    return response.getJSONArray("result");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Jackson configuration is set to fail on empty results.
From your exception:

```
(to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

However, there might be other reasons. It is difficult to say without seeing the implementation of `com.demo.earchengineclient.Client`.
If possible, try to replace JSONObject for JsonObject (the one from javax.json, that came with Java 8).

Comment: I have updated my client code implementation. if am invoking my client code alone, am able to get the response in JSONArray without any issue., But if i invoke via SpringBoot `@Controller` am getting this error.